# Get context in which a view is rendered?

Tags: wpf, mvvm

In my WPF application I have a viewmodel class called `CompanyViewModel`.

Sometimes, an instance of this class is set as the `DataContext` of my main window, which is defined like this:

```
<window x:Class= ..... >
    <Grid>
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding }"></ContentControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

In this case I want a view to be used that displays all the properties of the viewmodel.

Other times, a `ListView` control has its itemsource set as a collection containing instances of `CompanyViewModel`. Here, I want a view to be used that renders only some important properties.

I have this in the resource dictionary of `MainWindow.xaml`:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:CompanyViewModel}">
    <vw:CompanyView></vw:CompanyView>
</DataTemplate>
```

Is it possible to select a view for the viewmodel based on the context where the viewmodel is bound? For instance, to use `CompanyView` when displayed in the `ContentControl` of a window or when in a `TabControl`, and to use `CompanyViewSmall` where displayed in a `ListView`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DataTemplate` to use is first looked for locally, and then looked for further up the Visual Tree hierarchy if it's not found.

Because of this, you can specify the `DataTemplate` to use further down the hierarchy to use something different than normal.

For example, the following will use the `CompanyView` anywhere the `CompanyViewModel` is in the visual tree, except in the specific `ListView` where the `DataTemplate` is specified as the smaller view.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:CompanyViewModel}">
        <vw:CompanyView />
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>


<ListView>
    <ListView.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:CompanyViewModel}">
            <vw:CompanyViewSmall />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.Resources>
</ListView>
```

You could also use an implicit style for the `ListView` telling it to use the smaller template in the `.Resources`, however this will apply the smaller view to any `ListView`, not just specific ones, and if you ever apply another style to a `ListView` you'll have to remember to inherit the default style to keep the smaller `DataTemplate`.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListView}">
    <Style.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:CompanyViewModel}">
            <vw:CompanyViewSmall />
        </DataTemplate>
    </Style.Resources>
</Style>
```